# There is an endpoint connection error problem implementing the websocket with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

This is my `WebSocketConfig`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pub");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/sub");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

This is my `SocketController`:

```java
@Controller
public class SocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/comm/message")
    @SendTo("/sub/test")
    public Message message(Message message) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

I am testing the socket through Chrome's Web Socket Test Client and Advanced Rest Client, but my connection endpoint `ws://localhost:8080/socket` returns the error.

Is there anything I set wrong?

---

[connecting try tool and endPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOJmn.png)

[return message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enxV8.png)

Comment: What error is returned? Please be specific.

Comment: I don't receive any messages through any test device.
Of course, the project log also has no response.
That's why we can't find a solution.

Comment: Your question says, "...my connection endpoint `ws://localhost:8080/socket` returns the error." However, your comment indicates that you're *not* actually getting an error, just that you don't receive anything at all. Can you clarify which is actually the case?

Comment: Also, are you creating the subscriber before or after you send the message?

Comment: I think the websocket connection endpoint was activated through the text above.
So I tried to connect to ws://localhost:8080/socket through socket tool.
However, the tool returns the unknwon error and the project cannot check any messages.

Comment: What do you mean that, "the tool returns the unknwon error"?

Comment: I attached an image at the bottom of the body.
I think the endpoint should be activated, but the tool returns the connection failure.
I want to check if there are any settings I missed, but I'm also activating endpoints through webSocketConfig settings through other examples.

Comment: I checked the activation of ws://localhost:8080/socket when using addHandler through the new attempt WebSocketConfigurer.
However, the above attempt is not the way I want it.
I would like to use a stomp to implement the form of pub/sub.
Through the above attempt, I made this inference.
Stomp cannot be verified through any tool and can only activate the connection through new SockJs ("")?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Please, annotate with @EnableWebSocket your configuration class.